# Having Select All and Select None Button with in the drop down of Flex 4 Combobox

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

Flex 4 Combobox is extended with a Text Input that helps in getting to the item that is searched for.

I have created a Check Box as an itemrenderer for this Flex 4 Combobox. I would like to Add a Select All and Select None options in the drop down of the Combobox.

I know that i could accomplish by editing the dropdownfactory in case of a Flex 3 Combobox. But in Flex 4 the dropdownfactory doesnt exist.

Any help please.

Comment: A screenshot may help here.  The ComboBox is not really designed for multiple selection; so it sounds like it would be a big change to get that to work.  How would you display the prompt, for example?

Answer (score 1):

try this component....

http://arcadiocarballares.com/?p=637

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add in two extra items to the ComboBox: Select All, Select None in positions 0 and 1 of the dataProvider. Then when the user selects an item, check if it is 0 and 1 and act accordingly.

It should'nt really matter that all the items will not be highlighted, as the combobox will close anyway the moment the item is selected. I have had to add a Select None option before, and thats how I did it.

Brian